# BeautifulSoup4 not working on my Mac OS even with being installed

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, terminal

I am working on a web scraping project, my first two lines of code are:

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Output in vscode:

p/Capstone/Web_scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/nickruizmac/Desktop/Capstone/Web_scraper.py", line 2, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Through terminal here are my current versions of pip and python

Python:

python3 --version = 3.11.4

Pip:

pip -V = pip 23.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

I am on the newer side when it comes to the Mac OS so I am not as well versed in it as I would be with Windows. I believe it may be an issue of install location. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try : pip install bs4

Comment: I have and just re did that. Even when I install through terminal I see the same output of "no module named bs4"

Comment: No error in pip output ? You can also try this : python3 -m pip install bs4

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `beautifulsoup4` package using the `pip install beautifulsoup4` command.

If you already have it installed, choose the **correct** interpreter for the **Python** extension (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`).

[image]

You can use the `pip show beautifulsoup4` command to view the installation information of the `beautifulsoup4` package, including the installation location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not your computer that is the problem. I am using a Mac as I am responding to this very post and also use BeautifulSoup on it. In my IDE (PyCharm) you are having to install the package beforehand and only then use the code `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Usually you are having to "pip-install" it within your executer-terminal and thus achieve the same. To only write `import BeautifulSoup` won't do the trick.

(BTW, I would try changing the title to Soup instead of Soap, might lead to confusion.)

[image]